# get data of checked row from 1 dataGrid to another datagrid, delete unchecked row from other datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have 2 datagridview in WinForms
dgv1
dgv2
dgv1 has some columns including 1 CheckBoxColumn  ,dgv2 has Some columns but no CheckBoxColumn .
I want functionality which enables me , when i check CheckBoxColumn ,data of that particular Row should be selected and go into Dgv2 .
this is how i put selected rows from dgv1 to dgv2  .
But if i cancel check (or unckeck) ,checked checkBox in dgv1  that particular row should be deleted from dgv2 .
Help me to fix this . i'll be thankful of u guys ,looking forward to this. :)

here is my code
 consider datagridview6= dgv1 and datagridview10 = dgv2

```
private void dataGridView6_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView10.Visible = true;           
         if (dataGridView6.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 7)
            {
                if (dataGridView6.CurrentCell.Value != null)
                {
                    bool checkstate = (bool)dataGridView6.CurrentCell.Value;

                    if (checkstate == false)
                    {
                        dataGridView6.CurrentCell.Value = true;                                           
                    }
                else
                 {//here help in logic to delete unchecked row
                    dataGridView6.CurrentCell.Value = false;
                     int j= int.Parse(dataGridView6.Rows[e.RowIndex].ToString());
                     dataGridView10.Rows.Remove(dataGridView10.Rows[j]);
                  }
               }
         else
         {dataGridView6.CurrentCell.Value = true;
           dataGridView10.Rows.Insert(i);          dataGridView10.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value=dataGridView6.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
dataGridView10.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = dataGridView6.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
dataGridView10.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dataGridView6.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
           }
     }
```

/* in this logic checked row is being selected in dgv2 but on unchecking it delete is not working.

both data grid are not bound with database , m fetching value using SQlCommand class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To doing this you need to store `RowIndex` of `dgv2` in Checked Row's `Tag` property.

for example when you select any row from `dgv1` at this time you are adding that records in `dgv2` gridview. Now, you need to store that new row index of created row in `dgv1.CurrentRow`.

So, when the cell get unchecked you can find the added row from the `dgv2` by using that row index.

```
///Inserting default records
///The fifth column value is a primary key value
///Application will check that value with second grid and performs remove and add rows
///we cannot use row index to remove row. because the row index will be changed if any row removed from dgv2.
///I have placed this code in form load event.
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Nimesh", "Gujarat", "India", 1);
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Prakash", "MP", "India", 2);
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Rohit", "Maharashtra", "India",  3);
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Jasbeer", "Panjab", "India",  4);
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Venkteshwar", "Karnatak", "India", 5);
dgv1.Rows.Add(false, "Rony", "Delhi", "India", 6);


///We cannot use CellChange event becauase it will be executed after cell end edit.
///We cannot use CellContentClick event coz it will not call when you double click or clicking quickly multiple times.
///So we are using CellMouseUp event 


private void dgv1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv1.CurrentCell == null)
        return;

    dgv2.Visible = true;
    if (dgv1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool)dgv1.CurrentCell.GetEditedFormattedValue(e.RowIndex, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange);
        if (bValue)
        {
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dgv2.Rows.Count; iRow++)
            {
                if (dgv2.Rows[iRow].Tag != null && dgv2.Rows[iRow].Tag.Equals(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value))
                    return;
            }
            int iNewRowIndex = dgv2.Rows.Add();
            dgv2.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value;
            dgv2.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells[1].Value = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
            dgv2.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Cells[2].Value = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value;
            dgv2.Rows[iNewRowIndex].Tag = dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value != null)
            {
                for (int iRow = 0; iRow < dgv2.Rows.Count; iRow++)
                {
                    if (dgv2.Rows[iRow].Tag != null && dgv2.Rows[iRow].Tag.Equals(dgv1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value))
                    {
                        dgv2.Rows.RemoveAt(iRow);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh sorry it should be round bracket. I have updated my answer. tell me if u get any error

Comment: possible because, i have just placed a logic. can u tell me the line where the error is displaying

Comment: that's because the `dgv1.CurrentCell` is null. place another condition to check that if the current cell is null then cursor should return from the event.

Comment: @varsha have a look at the answer. i have updated it.

Comment: yes i know @varsha but, it wont work when u click on checkbox quickly multiple times. i have tested that. either row will be added or removed. you have to write that code in CellMouseUp event.

Comment: or it may add duplicate records. even you can't take RowIndex to determine which record should be removed. for example if u have selected 3 records and then u uncheck the 2nd record then it will be removed properly. but, when u try to uncheck 3rd record then application could not find 3rd index in the `dgv2` because there will be only two rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57986/discussion-between-shell-and-varsha).

Answer (score 0):

Add hidden columns on the both DataGridView.
When user check the checkboxcolumn assign some unique value to the hidden column.
Copy all the cells of the row from the first DataGridView to the second.
When user uncheck the check box, just find the row by the value of the hidden column.
`RemoveAt()` the row.